# Spring MVC + Spring Data aplication model

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, spring-mvc, spring-data

I must develop business application using Spring 3 MVC, Spring data and JPA. I searched some examples and I found few solutions. I chose two ways to design my webapp. The first one is (example for one entity):

```
@Entity
class Product {
//fields, methods
}

interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository <Product, Long>{}

interface ProductService {
//methods declaration
}

@Service
class ProductServiceImpl implements ProductService{
@Autowired
ProductRepository
//methods
}

@Controller
@RequestMapping("productsite")
class ProductController{
@Autowired
ProductServiceImpl
//render the model
}
```

and the second:

```
@Entity
class Product {
//fields, methods
}

 interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository <Product, Long>{
 //methods declaration
 }

 @Service
 class ProducDAO{
 @Autowired
 ProductRepository
 //methods
 }

@Component
class ProductEndpoint{
@Autowired
ProducDAO
//fields, methods
}

@Controller
@RequestMapping("productsite")
class ProductController{
@Autowired
ProductEndpoint
//render the model
}
```

Which solution is better and in accordance with the good practice ? Thanks for help.

Comment: DAO and repository are basically the same thing. I don't see any reason to have a repository use a DAO. What would be the responsibility of those two components. Also, when a component has an interface and an implementation, the interface must be autowired, and not the implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start as simple as you can. I think the first solution is good enough for most web application.